# how do you start a new activity from a single menu option

Tags: android, menuitem

Hi i am trying to open a new activity (GPSWptsEdit.class) with a single menu option (R.id.waypointEditId) but I am not having much luck with the code. Each time I run the GPSTrialActivity in debug mode in eclipse and click on the menu option I get a window pop up in eclispe called "Confirm Perspective Switch" when I click yes, the defualt instrumentation tab says "Source not found - The JAR file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platfoms\android-8\android.jar has no source attached.

If someone could assist with some suggestions, it would be much apreciated. Here is the code I have been playing with:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.waypointEditId:
        waypointEdit();
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void waypointEdit(){
     startActivity(new Intent(GPSTrialActivity.this, GPSWptsEdit.class));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're missing the `break` in your switch-case construction; try with this code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.waypointEditId:
        waypointEdit();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        break;
    }
}

public void waypointEdit(){
    Intent i = new Intent(GPSTrialActivity.this, GPSWptsEdit.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

But could you tell what is the problem? Which errors you get? What does the logcat say?

Comment: what is the different btw return true; and break; ?

Comment: @xDragonZ When I studied the `switch-case` construction they told me to ALWAYS put the `break;` at the end of every statement, otherwise the code will jump to the next case.

Comment: you must return `true` when you handled the `option`, `false` means you didn't handle the `option`

Comment: I my application I handle the Option Menu with a code that is similar to the I wrote in my answer - without `return true`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation , +1 , cuz in PHP I use `break;` but in android `return true;` that confuse me.

Comment: I did end up resolving the issue after reading the comments provided. Turns out that I forgot to ammend my: "setContentView(R.layout.wptedit);"

Answer (score 0):

i have used the same thing in my project and it was working well.

i used:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

         case R.id.add_new:
                        openDialog();
                        return true;

         case R.id.delete_all:
                          // some code
                          return true;
         default:
                          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void openDialog() 
{
        Intent intent=new Intent(ThisActivity.this,NewActivity.class);          
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();               
}
```

What problem do you get?

Comment: I did end up resolving the issue after reading the comments provided. Turns out that I forgot to ammend my: "setContentView(R.layout.wptedit);".

Answer (score 0):

add Activity GPSWptsEdit in menifest .

Comment: I did end up resolving the issue after reading the comments provided. Turns out that I forgot to ammend my: "setContentView(R.layout.wptedit);"

Answer (score 0):

I did end up resolving the issue, after reading the comments provided.
Turns out that, I forgot to amend this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.wptedit);
```